# Does mysql 5.0.22 support userdefined Functions?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.0

Does MySQL 5.0.22 Support user-defined functions\procedures ?

If yes, which is the easiest free editor to be preferred.
HeidiSQL is not supporting functions\procedures and MySQL workbenck is not fully supporting mySQL5.0.22.

Thanks,
Bipin

Comment: The first question is easily answered by looking at the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: You should **really** consider upgrading to a recent MySQL version. You are missing all the goodies otherwise and have to deal with such problems like this, which are a no brainer on current versions.